# What do these "preempted" Yarn commands do?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager

What does the following from Yarn do?

```
-preemptedAMContainers
-preemptedNonAMContainers
-preemptedResources='<memory:0\, vCores:0>'
```

Answer (score 1):

`preemptedAMContainers` is the number of Application Manager containers that were preempted.
`preemptedNonAMContainers` is the number of regular containers that were preempted.

YARN deals with containers but each container usually contains one task (map, reduce or AM).

`preemptedResources` is most likely a sum of the memory and vcores preempted.